# Me.undo to prevent changes when closing a form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I want to use the `ME.UNDO` command to prevent changes when closing a form in Access 2013.

I have a form that links to a table which contains a worklist. This form is read-only to prevent accidental changes.

To make changes, the user needs to double-click an item to bring up another form, which is related to this particular work item, then make changes on it.
I have a save button for the user to click to save the changes. If the user just **closes** this form, I do **not** want to save the changes.

I am using `me.undo` in the close event (and this is the only code line in that event). It is still saving the change in the worklist form.

Comment: plusone for the self-defeating title. `If Me.undone Then WoeIsMe`

Comment: You can't use the undo in the close event - that's too late. Take a look at this article: https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/810694-prevent-saving-when-just-closing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only writing a single record, and want to delete that record upon close, then try this. But First, Remove your **OnClose** event, notice that this fires on the **Unload** Event of the Form.

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer) 
   On Error Resume Next 
   DoCmd.SetWarnings False
   DoCmd.RunCommand (acCmdUndo)
   DoCmd.SetWarnings True 
End Sub
```

If the users can create multiple records, then this will only delete the last row inserted.